# Checking if tabpage exists, then create a new one if it doesn't

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

This is my coding

```
Thread groupid = new Thread(() => 
{
        while(true)
        {
            GroupIds.ForEach(delegate(String name)
            {
                if (tabControl1.TabPages.ContainsKey(name))
                {
                }
                else 
                    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(name);
            });
        }
});
```

For some reason, if I start the thread (which this loop checks if a new value in the list appears, then creating a new page. This code works to the point, it will show a new tab created with the value, then after about 1 second it says "Project is unresponsive" a.k.a it crashed. So I don't know how to fix it, I've tried !tabControl1.TabPages.Contains(name), and a different looping style. Even without the thread, it makes the new page then crashes immediately.

Comment: Since you're continuously delegating to the UI thread (I think...) then you'll always be blocking it, which causes it to be unresponsive. I think you need to rethink your design so you don't need another thread that's constantly checking for tab existence, and instead make use of events.

Comment: Unresponsive is different than crash. Much is wrong with the design - You need InvokeRequired, or what minitech said, would most likely answer your concerns

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the `tabControl` blocks the ProgramThread.  So you're actually blocking that thread non-stop.  Especially in such a tight loop, it will look like the application is unresponsive.

Comment: I mean, it actually says "Project has stopped working", and to debug. I've made an event handler that if an item gets added to the list, add it to the tabControl, it still crashes.

Comment: @Nom: I stand by my answer.  The debugger won't be able to status anything because of the blocking.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/8stp1, this is the screenshot. You can see in the textbox, it gains the groupid, and it adds to the tabcontrol box. The new code, i made an event handler where it looks like this.  void GroupIds_OnAdd(eventylist.EventyList<string> sender, string item)
        {
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(item);
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (!tabControl1.TabPages.Contains(tabPage2))
        {
            tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(1, tabPage2);
        }
```

this will check whether table page already exist, if not this will allow you to create one
.

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < TabControl.TabPages.Count; i++)
{
    if (TabControl.TabPages[i].Name == MyName)
    {
        TabControl.TabPages.Remove(RdpTabControl.TabPages[i]);
    }
}
```